# C++: Representation keyword of the instance itself inside a .cpp file defining functions of a class

Tags: c++, class, instance, keyword

For example, I create a class named `Circle` and define it in `Circle.h`.

```
class Circle {
    public:
        Circle *parent;

        Circle();
};
```

And in a separate `Circle.cpp` file under the same directory as `Circle.h`, I define the constructor.

```
Circle::Circle() {
    // creates a root circle, parent is set to itself
    *parent = ????
}
```

What should I fill in the `????` part? In AS3, I know you can use the `this` keyword to represent the instance itself when defining functions of the class. What do you use in C++?

**EDIT 2012/11/29 23:56**

There is another constructor:

```
Circle(Circle*);

Circle::Circle(Circle *cParent) {
    *parent = *cParent;
}
```

And a function, when called, creates a new `Circle` instance and set the new instance's `*parent` to caller.

```
void addChild();

void Circle::addChild() {
    Circle child(????);
}
```

`????` is still that mystery part. According to resources I have read, `this` seems to be deprecated or has become of other meanings?

Comment: Why would you need `parent` to point to itself?  That's what `this` is for.

Comment: parent = this; works... If it's what you need.

Comment: @JohnDibling - the **class** is defined in the header; it's non-inline member functions are defined in the source file.

Comment: @ThePluc:  That cannot be what OP needs.  It serves no useful purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't made it clear. I have another function that creates a new `Circle` instance and set the `*parent` to the function caller. You'll see in my edit.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Presumably, other constructors/functions set `parent` to point to other circles in other circumstances. I can imagine that serving a useful purpose; but the purpose is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @MikeSeymour:  It may be irrelevant to the actual question as asked, but they way this question was presented makes me think there is something just not right with what OP's trying to do.

Comment: @PeteBecker:  I'm reminded of a game of paper-scissors-rock-lizard-spock. Comment removed.

Comment: Where on earth did you read that `this` is deprecated? It's exactly the way to get the pointer you want.

Comment: Can you link the sources you have read whcich claim `this` is deprecated? Some book-burning is in order ]:->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is `this`; it's a pointer to the instance on which the function was invoked. In your example, you'd use it like this:

```
Circle::Circle()
{
  parent = this;
}
```

Note that it must be `parent = this;`, **not** `*parent = this;`. The latter would assign into the object `parent` is pointing to, which is not valid (`parent` has an indeterminate value). Fortunately, it wouldn't compile, as you'd be assigning a pointer into an object.

For cases such as this (initialising a data member inside a constructor), C++ has the initialiser syntax, which is generally preferred to assigning the members in the constructor body. The code would then look like this:

```
Circle::Circle()
  : parent(this)
{}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! So you mean `this` it self is a pointer to the instance itself, right?

Comment: @GreekFellows Yes, exactly. And it's **definitely** not deprecated.

Comment: I would even claim: it will never be deprecated. 8^)

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry. I'm new to C++ and learning a lot. Is the use of `this` keyword permitted only in defining functions of a class?

Comment: @GreekFellows Don't be sorry. It's good you're learning. Yes, `this` is only valid inside definitions of non-static member functions. In other context, there is no "instance on which the function was invoked," so it wouldn't have a well-defined meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Likewise, in C++ the `this` keyword is a pointer to the current object. Since it's a pointer, you should be assigning to the `parent` pointer directly instead of dereferencing it.

```
parent = this;
```

However, are you sure you want the parent of your circle to be itself? Often, the top-most object in a hierarchy has a null parent pointer:

```
parent = nullptr;
```

Or in a compiler that doesn't support `nullptr`, use `NULL` or `0`.

Since you didn't initialise your `parent` pointer to point at any valid `Circle` object, your code invokes undefined behaviour when you dereference it. You are then attempting to assign an object of type `Circle*` to an object of type `Circle`, which your compiler will complain about.

Comment: The top-most object in a hierarchy may well and sensibly have itself as parent, depending on the intended interpretation. Here parent could be *a circle containing this one*, and `*this` fits the bill.

Comment: To add to what @Walter said, one way of implementing a linked list is for the end nodes to contain pointers to themselves. Iteration through the list continues until `next == this`. The benefit of this approach is that dereferencing `next` has well-defined behavior without needing to check for a null pointer.

Comment: @Walter Of course, which is why I gave the first solution. Given the possibility that the asker might be doing the wrong thing, I thought it was worth pointing out the common case. Edited to make it not "strange".

Comment: I'm assigning the circle itself to its parent because of some other codes in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

> According to resources I have read, this seems to be deprecated or has
>   become of other meanings?

You're either reading bad resources or misreading them.  The `this` pointer is alive and well in C++(03|11).

Moving backwards, your mystery's solution is to use `this`:

```
void Circle::addChild() {
    Circle child(this);
}
```

This code is almost right:

```
Circle::Circle(Circle *cParent) {
    *parent = *cParent;
}
```

But not quite right becuase `*parent` dereferences `parent`, which isn't what you want to do.  What you want to do is assign the `parent` pointer, not make changes to the thing that `parent` points to:

```
Circle::Circle(Circle *cParent) {
    parent = cParent;
}
```

Simalarly with the ctor:

```
Circle::Circle() {
    // creates a root circle, parent is set to itself
    parent = ????
}
```

However in this case, since a root node has no parent conceptually, the `parent` member of that node shouldn't point to itself, but to nothing:

```
Circle::Circle() {
    // creates a root circle, parent is set to itself
    parent = NULL; // or '0' or 'nullptr' with C++11
}
```